# How do I get individual variables returned from pyautogui.getActiveWindow()?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've got the following running in python 3.9.13

```
>>>import pyautogui

>>> hwnd = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Untitled - Notepad")
>>> hwnd2 = pyautogui.getActiveWindow()

>>> hwnd
[Win32Window(hWnd=262986)]
>>> hwnd2
Win32Window(hWnd=461622)

>>> print(hwnd[0])
<Win32Window left="844", top="49", width="379", height="462", title="Untitled - Notepad">
>>> print(hwnd[0].top)
49
>>> print(hwnd[0].left)
844

>>> print(hwnd2[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Win32Window' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I get at the 'elements' in the hwnd2 (object?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what `print(hwnd2)` prints. `hwnd2` is not a list but just the object itself. So why put `[0]` behind it? Just access `hwnd2`, `hwnd2.left` etc.